# How to set active IonicSegmentButton with React/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set a specific segment button as active and I've been searching around on how to do this. It seems to be possible with Angular/Ionic, but I'm using React and am unable to find the React answer.

Here's the code:

```
<IonItem>
     <IonText>Status<IonText color="danger">*</IonText></IonText>
     <IonSegment id="event_status">
          <IonSegmentButton value="close">
               <IonLabel>Close</IonLabel>
          </IonSegmentButton>
          <IonSegmentButton value="open">
               <IonLabel>Open</IonLabel>
          </IonSegmentButton>
     </IonSegment>
</IonItem>
```

I want to set the close button as the active button

Comment: Try to set value on your main `<IonSegment id="event_status" value="close">` tag. i didn't  try it. but i hope it will work.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib you're a genius! it worked perfectly. Totally didn't think about doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it Worked for you posting as answer so other can get help too:

Try to set value on your main `<IonSegment id="event_status" value="close">` tag.

Hope it will work